# I keep getting failures installing modules at BEGIN { plan tests => 5 }. What do I need to get past this?

Tags: perl, cpan

The module it's failing to install is JSON::XS. Really it's failing to install anything 
that has the following code:

```
BEGIN { plan tests => 5 };
```

From the build.log:

```
syntax error at t/04_dwiw_encode.t line 13, near "plan tests"
```

The offending line:

```
 13     BEGIN { plan tests => 5 }
```

I read that there's a problem with Test.pm but there are quite a few modules
using it and furthermore this just started happening recently.

I just tried reinstalling perlbrew and also tried updating outdated modules
but I keep getting the same failures.

Any one have an idea what might have caused this and how to fix it?

Comment: What version of Test do you have installed? (`perl -MTest -le'print $Test::VERSION'`)

Comment: Also provide output of `perl -MTest -le'print $INC{"Test.pm"};'` (Feel free to sanitize user/company name by using "foo" instead, if applicable.)

Comment: My apologies; it's Test (not Test::More) that matters. See the new comments I left.

Comment: Where I'm going with this: I suspect you either have an outdated version of the module, or you're picking up one of your own modules called `Test.pm`.

Comment: It's telling me Can't locate JSON/XS.pm in @INC at /home/path/monitor/lib/Test.pm  where Test.pm is something that I made. The rest is @ INC which is too big to paste here.

Comment: Rename your module. There is already one named `Test.pm`, and JSON::XS is trying to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you either have an older-than-expected version of the [`Test`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test) module, or you created your own module named `Test.pm` and it's getting picked up instead of the expected module.

You can address the first issue by upgrading Test.

```
cpan Test
```

You should address the second issue by renaming your `Test.pm` to something else, but you might also be able to address it by changing directory and temporarily clearing the `PERL5LIB` env var.

```
pushd / ; PERL5LIB= cpan JSON::XS ; popd
```

Comment: I do have my own Test.pm.  I change that and see if it helps. Thanks.

Comment: I just renamed my module. Thanks for the help.